# Comparing session data with form data

Tags: php, session

ok, here's the situation:
Checking out at an online shop, i've a multi-page form.
user can check out without registering - no probs so far.
If a user already has an account, the eg address form will be filled with his (in MySQL DB) stored data - no probs so far as well.
All data is stored in the current session.

Now here's the question:
If the user changes his address data, how am i aware of it? I can do a data compare at the end of the checkout process, comparing the db data with the session data and see if or what fields have been changed.
Would that be a possible way to go?
Or what would be an efficient and least anoying (for the user) way to handle checking data for possible changes?

Comment: @RyanVincent What if i was buying for my girlfriend?

Comment: The form is broken down into a billing and a shipping address part.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito
I'm looking for a possible way to handle this. Doesn't make sense to try out this and that without knowing upfront whether it does make sense at all or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can put event handlers on the address that field and the compare the new value with the values you have in session(or database).

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" onchange="compareData" />
</form>

<script>
function compareData(){
var address = document.getElementById("address");
var sessionAddress = <?php echo $_SESSION['address']); ?>;
var result = address.localeCompare(sessionAddress);
//do what you want with result
}
</script>
```

Comment: does that mean i have to loop through all the (billing and shipping) address fields?

Comment: It depends on what you plan to achieve but then its always best to use the most recent data so if the address field changes, use the data on the form rather than the data in the DB.